# Get the first commit date of a Linux stable branch

Tags: linux, git, merge

I want to get the commit date of the first patch in a Linux stable branch. According to Wikipedia, the Linux 3.2 has been created on **Jan 5, 2012.**

And I choose the `git rev-list` command:

```
git rev-list --merges --boundary --format="%cd" |tail -1  (Wed **Jan 4** 15:03:06 2012 -0800)
git rev-list --merges --format="%cd" | tail -1 (Sun Apr 17 14:47:24 2005 -0700) 
git rev-list --no-merges --boundary --format="%cd" (Wed **Jan 4** 15:03:49 2012 -0800)
git rev-list --no-merges --format="%cd" (Sat Apr 16 15:20:36 2005 -0700)
```

The interesting thing is that for the patch I got using the command `git rev-list --merges --boundary --format="%cd" |tail -1` is the following:

```
The date is (Wed Jan 4 15:03:06 2012 -0800)
```

The summary is: `minixfs: misplaced checks lead to dentry leak`

Yet the patch from the command: `git rev-list --no-merges --boundary --format="%cd" |tail -1` is the following:

The summary: `Merge git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/davem/net`

And definition of rev-list:

```
--boundary
Output uninteresting commits at the boundary, which are usually not shown.

--merges
Print only merge commits. This is exactly the same as --min-parents=2.

--no-merges
Do not print commits with more than one parent. This is exactly the same as --max-parents=1.
```

My questions are:

1. Why do we have to add `--boundary` to get the first commit?
2. Why the no-merge patch has two parents while merge patch has only one parent ? Is it because of the rev-list ?